# DataList paging with search result

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, paging, datalist

i have a DataList to display tons of items, so i use paging and search method in order to filter and makes it easier, both are working fine. however, when it comes to paging after search, the data will back to (SELECT *) but not the specific item im searching for

what i done so far:

```
    SqlDataAdapter adap;
    DataSet ds;
    PagedDataSource adsource;
    int pos;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            this.ViewState["vs"] = 0;
            pos = (int)this.ViewState["vs"];

            databind();
            databind2();
        }
     }

public void databind()
    {
        adap = new SqlDataAdapter("select p.item_code as pitem, i.LongDesc as longname, p.SellPrice_1 as normalprice, p.SellPrice_2 as memberprice from plu p inner join item i on p.item_code = i.item_code WHERE p.publish =1 order by i.LongDesc", constr);
        ds = new DataSet();
        adsource = new PagedDataSource();
        adap.Fill(ds);
        adsource.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
        adsource.PageSize = 16;
        adsource.AllowPaging = true;
        adsource.CurrentPageIndex = pos;
        CategoryList.DataSource = adsource;
        CategoryList.DataBind();
    }
```

the filter part shows as below

```
public void Filter_Command(Object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName.Equals("Filter"))
        {
            adap = new SqlDataAdapter("select p.item_code as pitem, i.LongDesc as longname, p.SellPrice_1 as normalprice, p.SellPrice_2 as memberprice, d.department_code as dcode, d.category_code as dcatecode, c.category_code as ccode from plu p inner join item i on p.item_code = i.item_code inner join EPO_PDU_department d on d.department_code = i.department_code inner join EPO_PDU_Category c on c.category_code = d.category_code WHERE p.publish =1 AND c.category_code = '" + e.CommandArgument.ToString() + "'order by i.LongDesc  ", constr);
            ds = new DataSet();
            adsource = new PagedDataSource();
            adap.Fill(ds);
            adsource.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
            adsource.PageSize = 16;
            adsource.AllowPaging = true;
            adsource.CurrentPageIndex = pos;
            btnprevious.Enabled = !adsource.IsFirstPage;
            btnnext.Enabled = !adsource.IsLastPage;
            CategoryList.DataSource = adsource;
            CategoryList.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

buttons that i used:

```
protected void btnprevious_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pos = (int)this.ViewState["vs"];
        pos -= 1;
        this.ViewState["vs"] = pos;
        databind();
    }

    protected void btnnext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pos = (int)this.ViewState["vs"];
        pos += 1;
        this.ViewState["vs"] = pos;
        databind();
    }
```

searching and paging are working fine without each other. but i would like them to work together. thanks

******* UPDATE *******

in case Rik needs more information
[image: the errors occurred]

Comment: After button click you are binding unfiltered data 'databind()'

Comment: i do noticed that but im not sure how should i fix that

Comment: Make your databind apply the filter if any

Comment: @Rik mmmmm, like how? can you please show me what's the idea in your mind? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make you databind apply filter, if any

```
public void databind(string filter = null)
{
    var filterQuery = "";
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter)){
        filterQuery = " AND c.category_code = '" + filter + "'";
        this.ViewState.ContainsKey("filter") 
            ? this.ViewState["filter"] = filter
            : this.ViewState.Add("filter", filter);
    }

    var query = "select p.item_code as pitem, i.LongDesc as longname, p.SellPrice_1 as normalprice, p.SellPrice_2 as memberprice from plu p inner join item i on p.item_code = i.item_code WHERE p.publish =1";
    query += filterQuery;
    query += " order by i.LongDesc";

    adap = new SqlDataAdapter(query, constr);
    ds = new DataSet();
    adsource = new PagedDataSource();
    adap.Fill(ds);
    adsource.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
    adsource.PageSize = 16;
    adsource.AllowPaging = true;
    adsource.CurrentPageIndex = pos;
    CategoryList.DataSource = adsource;
    CategoryList.DataBind();
}
```

and then filter command:

```
public void Filter_Command(Object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
{
     string filter = e.CommandName.Equals("Filter") ? e.CommandArgument.ToString() : null;
     databind(filter);
}
```

and your buttons

```
protected void btnprevious_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pos = (int)this.ViewState["vs"];
    pos -= 1;
    this.ViewState["vs"] = pos;
    databind(this.ViewState["filter"]);
}

protected void btnnext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pos = (int)this.ViewState["vs"];
    pos += 1;
    this.ViewState["vs"] = pos;
    databind(this.ViewState["filter"]);
}
```

Make sure `this.ViewState["filter"]` is defined (You can do the same as for your `this.ViewState["vs"]`

Comment: interesting code, but it shows me that filterSource and filterEvents are not yet declare, so should i?

Comment: your edited has 2 viewstate at the button, i believe the word filter in button belongs to databind right? it needs to be declare or it should be filter = this.ViewState["filter"]; ???

Comment: Sorry, I am a bit short on time. You should also do some checks on the viewstate filter. Viewstate is an array so that's ok. Will update this afternoon. Hope this will get you going.

Answer (score 0):

You can Create a generic databind function which will expect Parameter for search also. .. then use this function everywhere.

Comment: do you mean i can actually set "WHERE item = ??? " at the databind and so when i search and paging will proceed with no problem? i tired that but unfortunately im using e.command ("filter") so im not able to do as the method